# Cross-platform best MVC model-to-controller messaging approach (C#, Objective-C++)

Tags: c#, c++, model-view-controller, c++11, objective-c++

Planning to rewrite a complex, UI-heavy app so that its model is as cross-platform as reasonably possible.  The research / reading I've done makes sense conceptually, but in terms of the model sending messages to the controller in some sort of cross-platform approach, I'm not seeing what a best practices approach would entail.

For example, the Model is changed via the Controller making calls to the Model's API.  But the Model is then responsible for informing clients of its data that a change has taken place, so it needs to broadcast that back to the Controller -- which needs to inform the View(s).

But messaging approaches are going to be different for a controller written in C# or Objective-C++, right?  Would one use signal to connect to the Controller, which would use platform-specific message communication with the View(s)?

Is there a standard, lightweight template that sets up these best practices for the platform-independent model operations?

Comment: "But messaging approaches are going to be different for a controller written in C# or Objective-C++, right?" Not only that, but the MVC pattern for Cocoa/Objective-C is actually somewhat different from what other platforms call MVC, so you might find some difficulty there as well.

Comment: So then what would be a best practice approach for the Model?  Have functions that notify the Controller that a model change has occurred,then let each platform-dependent Controller implementation handle 100% of all MVC messages?

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting to start a project that does much the same thing.  I was planning on using boost::signals2 as the callback mechanism.  It uses standard C functions for the callbacks so it should work with just about any language.  You can write all your models in C++ and inform the controllers of changes via the signals2 callbacks.

Of course this limits you to a C-style interface to/from your models but as far as I know that's the only way to go if you want it to work across platforms.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's rather difficult to use unified controllers along with native (iOS, MFC, HTML, ...) views.

I, personally, create a complete and headless API to my application. It's this API that I expose to manipulate the model (internal) and view (external).

This approach utilizes a centralized & unified "master" controller (my API). This component doesn't *need* to be strictly MVC. Each platform has a separate (sub) controller that bridges your internal API and the platform-native view.

It's a layered approach. As far as the messaging mechanism, C++ callbacks (Boost Function & Bind) work well enough for simple tasks. Boost Signals, as recommended by @Rotsiser_Mho, is more robust.

C++ is a good option for your core as it can be intermixed with nearly any platform. Even Android will let you link in native code with the NDK.

If the view is too complex (lots of custom visualization & such), you might want to use a cross platform U.I. toolkit, such as WX, QT, GTK, Cairo, OpenGL, Swing, etc. If you go that route, you can use the built-in native signaling system and controller design.

Comment: If we may be using various UI toolkits, (such as QT), plus Mac OS / IOS / Android / .net, would it make sense to create a cross-platform messaging layer, and would that reside in the model?

Would the model need to keep track of what controllers were interested in what data -- or is that information handled inside a central Controller?